# This python code in C/C++

Tags: c++, python, c

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib

print 'Insert page to download:'
page = raw_input()

filehandle = urllib.urlopen(page)
myFile = open('file.html','w')

for lines in filehandle.readlines():
    myFile.write(lines  )

myFile.close()
filehandle.close()
```

This basically just downloads the inputed webpage and writes it to file.html.

I would like to know how can I do this using C/C++. If there is a way but it is not so straight forward as python, what can I do or search to get to a similar result?

Also, I am aware of the existence of socket programming but I am not yet very good with it and I am just searching for a quick and dirty solution.

Thank you.

Comment: What OS are you using? Also, do you want a solution in C or in C++? It's not the same language.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. I know they are now the same language, but a solution would be better for C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second libcurl, that is what I usually use for my quick and dirty solutions.

Usually when you program within a desktop environment (like GNOME and KDE) , you can use functionality from that environment that is made to be used within the GUI and is easier to use with the file chooser window, progress-bar et.c.

If you program for a GNOME environment (or have the GNOME libraries installed), then this program almost do the same thing as your Python program, except it doesn't transform end-of-line characters, it copies CR and LF verbatim, and it use the program arguments instead of prompting the user for input. Oh, and it gives no error messages, it just exits without any clue to why. But it do have the advantage that it can copy between any two files, local or in a remote file system, that gnome can handle, and you can use file names without a path or using ~ for your home directory.

```
/*
 File: mycopy.c

 Compile with: gcc -Wall -g -c mycopy.c `pkg-config --cflags gio-2.0`
 Link with: gcc -Wall -g mycopy.o -o mycopy `pkg-config --libs gio-2.0`

 See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726499/this-python-code-in-c-c
*/

#include <glib-object.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char*argv[])
{   GFile *source, *dest;
    gboolean success;

    if( argc!=3 )
        exit( 2 );

    g_type_init();


    source  = g_file_new_for_commandline_arg( argv[1] );
    dest    = g_file_new_for_commandline_arg( argv[2] );

    success = g_file_copy( source, dest, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );

    if( !success )
        exit( 2 );

    exit( 0 );
}
```

If you want copying from a web-page really fast in Linux, then you mount the directory (a.k.a. "the web site") into your file-system and use splice (see `man 2 splice`) in your code to transfer the data. I haven't checked this recently, but most ready-made libraries didn't do that last time I checked. You can also (preferably?) do this with the shell commands `mount` and `cp` (last time I benchmarked, this was faster then C code using libcurl, or the curl or wget shell commands, for any large-ish file).

Comment: Well! Thank you very must for this!!

Answer (score 5):

Try the [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) library, which provides URL download functions for C (and many other languages including C++).

If you're writing code for Windows, you can also use the [Windows Internet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385331%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) library.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty answer is to use that python code and shell out from your C++ code, or embed python and run that code...

Anyway what you want is an http client library for C/C++.  I've experience with [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) from C and it is about as pleasant as that sort of thing gets!